# Visual Studio 2019 - Lost References

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Following a hardware failure I have installed VS2019 (16.7.2) on my new system. My old system had 16.4.2. I've cloned my git repos to the new machine but VS cannot find the references in my 16.4.2 projects. I've tried deleting a reference and adding it back manually by browsing to the dll but VS can't see it. I can create and compile a new project without any problems.

I'm guessing there's something missing from 16.7.2 (or perhaps something there that shouldn't be?).

Each reference (e.g. Microsoft.CSharp, System...) has the yellow warning triangle and when I check properties for the reference path is empty.

Grateful for any advice.

Comment: Right click the references and check that the location of the files are in the right folders.  Or you can open the csproj file in Notepad which is easier the right clicking every reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - because of bad paths for NuGet project(s).  I made a backup copy of my CSProj file, then I manually edited it with a text editor to remove the bad error references for the NuGet.
Here's a link to someone else's description of a similar problem.
https://makolyte.com/referenced-component-could-not-be-found/